# Y scale on ggplot2 bar graph makes no sense

Tags: r, csv, graph, ggplot2, charts

My bar graph has a weird Y Axis that skips around seemingly at random, from -1.7% to -10.1%, -10.3%, and then to -2%. You can see it below:

[image: My bar graph with the messed up y axis]

Here is my code:

```
library(ggplot2)

healthd = read.csv("R/states.csv")

states = healthd[[1]]
insuredChange = healthd[[4]]
ggplot(data = healthd, aes(x = states, y = insuredChange)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity") +
theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

What's going on here? How do I fix it?

Also, how can I get the x axis labels to all be right justified on the same line?

Comment: Check the class of your axis Y's values. If it's not numeric, this problem can happen.

Comment: `insuredChange` is probably a character or possibily a factor, not a `numeric`. `class(healtd$insuredChange)` to check.

Comment: Note that the axis breaks aren't random. They're alphabetical. The "%" sign is causing the problem. Do `healthd$insuredChange = as.numeric(as.character(gsub("%","",healthd$insuredChange)))`. Then rerun the plot code.

Comment: It says `> class(healthd$insuredChange)`
`[1] "NULL"`

Comment: @eipi10 after doing that I get: `Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "insuredChange", value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 52`

Comment: Pretty difficult to help more without a fully reproducible version of your data.

Comment: See [how to create a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Seems like you might not have column names in your data.frame? You really should check `class(insuredChange)`. Note that R won't read in columns with percent signs as numeric. This is really a problem with you importing your data and not ggplot. However you haven't shown what the input looks like so it's difficult to help.

Comment: Here's the data source: https://www.kaggle.com/hhs/health-insurance/

Comment: Also, if you look above you will see that I already checked the class and received NULL @MrFlick

Comment: You checked the class of heathd$insuredChange, not insuredChanged. From your example I would bet they are different.

Comment: @MrFlick I think you're confused. I never used any `insuredChanged` variable. I don't know where you got that from.

Comment: G.T - MrFlick is quite accurate as your comment above is "It says `> class(healthd$insuredChange) [1] "NULL" – G.T. 2 hours ago` - did you look at my answer below?

Comment: You have the line `insuredChange = healthd[[4]]` and you used `aes(y = insuredChange)` in the code you provided above. I'm guessing that `names(healthd)[4] != "insuredChange"` so it's that local variable that's being used, not values from the data.frame.

Comment: I never used the variable `insuredChanged`

Answer (score 0):

First - what you present isn't a reproducible example and nobody wants to sign up to access your data to help you out...

In your code:

```
states = healthd[[1]]
```

and

```
insuredChange = healthd[[4]]
```

are assigning the columns to the global environment - they are not changing the name of the values in your data.frame. When you use ggplot it is looking for columns in your data.frame with the names that don't exist - hence the `NULL` statement

```
 healthd$states = healthd[[1]]
 healthd$insuredChange = healthd[[4]]
```

will change it to something that should work - though I don't have the data so am not completely sure.

This should now generate the figure you want.

```
ggplot(healthd, aes(states, insuredChange)) +
       geom_bar(stat="identity") +
       theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```